# Android/Java Abstract Class Inheritance Issue

Tags: java, android, inheritance, abstract-class

I'm having an issue with inheritance between 2 classes and a single normal class.  Here is an example of what I have:

Abstract ClassA
      function get_name();

Abstract ClassB extends ClassA

ClassC extends ClassB

Now, when I create an object of ClassC, I can't access the get_name() function.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.  Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: I threw together a trivial test case and it worked fine with package-scope access.  Can you provide source code, or at least what the failure message and/or failing instruction is?

Answer (score 3):

get_name() must be a protected or public function for ClassC or ClassB to access it.

If you don't have one of these parameters declared in ClassA, only ClassA will be able to use get_name();

```
public class ClassA
{
    protected CharSequence get_name()
    {
         return "ClassA";
    }
}
```

Think about it, it doesn't make much sense to have an abstract private function, since no other object will ever be able to implement it or access it.

Comment: Without a word in front it is package not private